# Import Vue library dynamically

Tags: typescript, vue.js, npm

I would like to be able to import Vue library dynamically in my Vue app. For instance, I would do like this :

```
const myPackage = import("https://www.npmjs.com/package/konect-matrices")
myPackage.doSomething()
```

Is it possible to do something similar ?
Thanks for the help :)

I searched some existing NPM libraries to be able to get NPM packages directly in the browser but nothing relevant.

Comment: This is what unpkg and other CDNs are for